# Can't create a user roles in database first approche

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to use an Identety with Asp.net MVC. Created a database, changed the default connection to my db connection and authentication is working fine. Now I am creating a new user role following this tutorial:
https://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2898/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-identity-for-mvc
It works fine with default model, roles are shown, but first it is not listed in existing db table, so I tryed to change the create role method the following way.

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            context.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole { Name = "admin" });

            try
            {
                userContext.AspNetRoles.Add(new AspNetRole()
                {
                    Name = collection["RoleName"]
                });
                userContext.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Role doesn't create. I think it is because of null id but have no idea how it is generated. Am I doing it in a right way if consider that database is existing on sql server? Tables are generated. Or is there any tutorial on how to do that?

Comment: Try using [the RoleManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.rolemanager-1.createasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: I tryed. But it sims to be only available for .Net core. But I am using .Net framework

Comment: Just create a new Guid as ID, ID is PK to the tabel so you should provide one. Last project I worked on, I just inserted the roles through SSMS, if providing an ID doesnt work :D

Comment: Actually I figured it out. I scroud up with db context and used this in a role creation process I used IdentityDbContext instead of IdentityDbContext that I provided in identity model. Strangly for me, Identety context worked and saved roles somewhere. I would be grateful if someone will explain me a logic behind it.